# Bootstrap 4 position overlapping and sizing issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I'm making a website which for purposes of examining the issue is https://jf-wd.github.io/Portfolio. If you look at the about `dropleft` component on the top navbar the dropdown menu is overlapped by the carousel I have, the carousel is part of me just learning bootstrap and it's not permanent but I'd like to know why it's overlapping the dropdown. I've tried countless methods found here on stack and other resources, but none of them are fixing my issue

My second issue is that on mobile or any small breakpoint on pc, the first image of the carousel takes the whole screen, but the second image just doesn't scale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, please include your code in your post, rather than just a link. Not only does this allow us to assist by looking at the code directly instead of going to your side and inspecting it, but, if your link doesn't work in the future, no one will know what you are referring to and the question becomes irrelevant for learning purposes.

As for the overlapping issue, this is due to a [Stacking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) issue. You can correct this by adding `position: relative` and `z-index: 2` to your `header` element. The value of `z-index` can be a higher value  if you like to be safe.

Comment: Thank you that worked and i forgot about the code sanippets sorry, but could you explain why adding relative positioning and a z-index to the header fixes the issue rather than just the dropdown itself?